# Is the class of inner-anodyne morphisms right-cancellative with respect to the of the class of monomorphisms?

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff

### Recall:

Given a category $A$, and two classes of morphisms $S,S'$, we say that $S$ is *right-cancellative with respect to $S'$* if for any pair of maps $f\in S, g\in S'$ such that $gf$ is defined, we have the implication $gf\in S \Rightarrow g\in S$.

Recall that the class of inner-anodyne morphisms in the category of simplicial sets is defined to be the class $\operatorname{llp}(\operatorname{rlp}(E))$, where $E$ denotes the set of inner-horn inclusions $\iota^n_k:\Lambda^n_k \hookrightarrow \Delta^n$ for $0<k<n.$

### Question:

Is the class of inner-anodynes right-cancellative with respect to the class of monomorphisms?  This is certainly the case for the Joyal-trivial cofibrations, but being inner-anodyne is a rather stronger condition.

Comment: Incidentally, do you know if right plus left anodyne implies inner anodyne? 

Comment: @Akhil: The map $\Delta[1] \to \Delta[2]$ induced by $\delta_1 : [1] \to [2]$ is both left and right anodyne, but it's not inner anodyne since it's not bijective on $0$-simplices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that in $\operatorname{Set}_{\Delta}$ the class of inner anodyne maps has the right cancellation property (within the class of monomorphisms) was proven by Danny Stevenson in his 2016 paper [*Stability for inner fibrations revisited*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07699), which was also published in [*TAC*](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/33/19/33-19abs.html).

Comment: Absolute necromancer! Better late than never! Thanks!

Comment: The reason why this is particularly nice is that it shows that the smallest weakly-saturated right-cancellative class of morphisms containing the spine inclusions is exactly the inner anodynes.  Joyal was only able to show this for trivial cofibrations, but this is a much stronger result!

Comment: Indeed. Cf. Lemma 3.5 in Joyal and Tierney's [*Quasi-categories vs. Segal spaces*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607820).